# ¿Diferencias entre epoch y timestamp?

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp

Creía que **epoch** y **timestamp** representaban el mismo valor, con la misma cifra, aunque obteniendo valores con `getTime()` de la clase `Timestamp` en Java, esto no es así.

El *valor de epoch* parece ser el obtenido por el método mencionado entre / 1000, es decir que **el tiempo epoch se mide en segundos** y **el timestamp en milisegundos**. He consultado varias páginas y no aclara la diferencia. Parece que timestamp, indica un momento determinado, pero tiene diferentes implementaciones según el lenguaje, y por ejemplo, en *mysql* ni siguiera se representa como una cifra.

Comment: No, Epoch y Timestamp no es lo mismo. Epoch es la fecha del 1 de Enero de 1970 a la medianoche, mientras que Timestamp es la fecha y hora actual, calculando a partir de Epoch. Quizá la clase [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) ayude a comprenderlo mejor.

Comment: Secundo lo que comenta @A.Cedano. Epoch es un instante de tiempo de referencia, comunmente en computacion se utiliza la fecha del 01/01/1970. Mientras que un timestamp es otro instante de tiempo de interes, por ejemplo el momento en que se escribio este comentario.